# Sqlite Query replacing a column with a column from another table

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables, one is indexing the other.

I am querying Table#1, and it has one column (string) that has an ID in it that corresponds to a unique row in Table#2. Im trying to write a query in Sqlite that allows me to retrieve the value from Table#2 if the column value in Table#1 is not an empty string.

Kinda like:

```
"SELECT TMake,TModel,TTrim,IYear,[%q] AS TPart1 FROM AppGuide WHERE TPart1 != ''"
```

But instead of retrieving the Index value (TPart1) Id like to get the string from Table#2.

Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT TMake,
       TModel,
       ...,
       (SELECT stringvalue
        FROM Table2
        WHERE Table2.ID = Table1.TPart1)
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.TPart1 != ''
```

However, these are rather slow to execute, so you'd better use a join (this returns exactly the same result):

```
SELECT Table1.TMake,
       Table1.TModel,
       ...,
       Table2.stringvalue
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.TPart1 = Table2.ID
WHERE Table1.TPart1 != ''
```

If you don't want to get records from `Table1` that have no matching `Table2` record, drop the `LEFT`.